# Retreive lost emails on Incredimail app with Flash player in 2021

Tags: flash

Good day

I am trying to retreive lost emails.  This problem is full of old technology.  Incredimail shut it's doors in 2020,  Adobe Flash player is not supported in 2021, and the OS of the computer is a 32bit Windows XP.

I uninstalled Adobe Flash player because it displayed an immovable icon on the desktop all of the time.

**The problem is that the Incredimail app uses flash player to run**.  The result is that I cannot open the application and export the emails.

Is there a way to retreive the emails in inbox/sent/archived folders?

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Adobe removed the flash player download link from their website in 2021. Even if you have a spare copy of the installer on your computer, it still won't work as it's an "online installer" that retreives a copy of the latest version from Adobe's website, which Adobe also deleted in 2021 so the installers Adobe provided for free download in 2020 won't work in 2021. However I managed to get an **offline** installer that works for Windows, Mac, Linux, ActiveX, NPAPI and PPAPI. No internet connection is needed and it's version 32.0.0.465 the latest version. https://gitlab.com/desbest/flash-player

Comment: Also in 2021 the web browsers Edge, Chrome and Firefox removed support for Flash and all NPAPI plugins. So if you want a web browser that supports flash, use Basilisk http://basilisk-browser.org

Comment: Flash Player removal took place 2 or 3 days ago automatically.  So there is no hope there. Ask Incredimail Support if they can help.

Comment: "Incredimail shut it's doors in 2020" @John

Comment: If that is the case then retrieving the mail is hopeless.

Comment: @debest The link of the offline installer allowed me to open the Incredimail application and to export the mails.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You can take help of this tiny little utility - **RecoveryTools
IncrediMail Migrator** to retrieve lost emails from Incredimail application. As Incredimail support is shutdown already so you have limited choice with you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Incredimail 2.5 can use eM ckient. It can convert files.
https://www.emclient.com/?lang=en&_ga=2.87103195.2139643426.1614441048-2130051183.1614441048

My incredimal was version 2.0 and had to convert the emails manually, but with great support from eM Client.

Answer (score 1):

To install IM run `install_flash_player.exe` and `install_flash_player_ax.exe`. Flash files are included to operate IM.
For Win XP delete or rename the files in `C:\WINDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash` (`Flash32_32_0_0_445.ocx` and `FlashUtil32_32_0_0_445_ActiveX.exe`)

Ocx and exe files older versions are renamed as deleted or renamed after which you can open IM with clock and notifier.

For Win 7 or later, replace and rename the files in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\` `Flash32_32_0_0_446.ocx` and `FlashUtil32_32_0_0_446_ActiveX.exe`.

For Win 10 run (reinst_flash_w10.cmd)